# Use node.js module in a Titanium app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, titanium

Currently I am writing a small Titanium app for testing. I need to include a module from NPM to titanium.

In this case I am trying with https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client

I am having the error saying Titanium couldn't find module.

The code I used for include is

`var DDPClient = require("./lib/node_modules/ddp");`

Can I use node.js modules in Titanium?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`require('./lib/node_modules/ddp/lib/ddp-client.js');`

It's very likely this module won't work for you. It has a lot of dependencies that use NodeJS specific modules, and specific APIs.

Luckily, someone has already written a module to connect to a Meteor server using DDP (I plead complete ignorance of this protocol and stack, by the way):

https://github.com/yubozhao/Ti.Meteor

Answer (score 2):

You can use try this module https://github.com/smclab/titaniumifier

> Get a Titanium™ SDK CommonJS module out of a Node package!

Comment: Welcome. This answer is very brief, perhaps you could supply some more details such as an example?

Answer (score 2):

Titanium now has partial support for npm modules: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Node.js_Support

For Alloy projects, do your `npm install` commands in `app/lib` so that your packages are stored in `app/lib/node_modules`.

For non-alloy projects, do your `npm` install in `Resources/` so that your packages are stored in `Resources/node_modules`.

Note that you may have problems with packages that rely on native node modules.

Comment: Do you know how to add native node modules?

Answer (score 0):

sure, why can't?

here is an example using node module in Alloy project:

1.install q.js, which will create a folder named "node module" and contain some files :

```
$ npm install q
$ find node_module
node_modules/
node_modules/q
node_modules/q/README.md
node_modules/q/queue.js
node_modules/q/package.json
node_modules/q/q.js
node_modules/q/LICENSE
```

2.copy the q.js to your app/lib/ folder:

```
$ mkdir app/lib
$ cp node_modules/q/q.js app/lib
```

3.declare it in your Titanium file:

```
// in app/alloy.js
Q = require('q')
```

4.use it in your controller:

```
// app/controllers/index.js:
var defer = Q.defer();
```

refer to: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154529/how-to-use-nodejs-modules-with-titanium#answer-285207

Comment: I have installed the node module and copied it into the project., But still didn't work. I have installed node module `request.js` and copied it to `app/lib` folder, now the build is throwing error, `module  not found - http.js`, The module request .js is using http.js within itself, do i have to install all dependencies ?