# Using node modules in Appcelerator Titanium Alloy Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

Can we use Node.js Modules in Appcelerator Alloy Project, I have followed the steps mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28006750/3733561),

1. `npm install request`
2. Copied the `request.js` into my `app/lib/` folder
3. Use the module as `var = require('request')`

The module is found by the compiler but request.js has dependencies,

```
//Inside request.js
'use strict'

var http = require('http')
  , https = require('https')
  , url = require('url')
  , util = require('util')
  , stream = require('stream')
  , zlib = require('zlib')
  , hawk = require('hawk')
    ...
```

`request.js` is using so many other modules, `http, https, util, stream ...`

Here are my questions

1. Is this the correct way of using node js modules ?
2. Do i have to install the dependencies ( https, util, stream ..) to use `request.js` node module ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, NodeJS support is added in SDK 6.0.0. See this URL for more information about requiring the modules in your project:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_6.0.0.GA_Release_Note-section-src-48432896_TitaniumSDK6.0.0.GAReleaseNote-NodeJSsupport

Comment: Can you share an example of how to require node modules ?
I don't see any examples in the appcelerator docs link you posted.